# How do I remove Twitter and Facebook from Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, sharing, facebook, twitter

I want to remove Twitter and Facebook (in the future) from Mountain Lion.

Is it enough to simply remove `Twitter.sharingservice` from

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ShareKit.framework/Versions/A/Plugins
```

What about all these other entries:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework
/System/Library/Accounts/Access
/System/Library/Accounts/Authentication
/System/Library/CoreServices/SocialPushAgent
/System/Library/InternetAccounts/
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.twitterd.plist
/System/Library/Messages/Plugins/FaceTime.imservice
/System/Library/SocialServices
```

Comment: It's hard to see this getting another good answer so unless you are planning to write up the steps you performed, you might want to edit this to explain _why_ simply not signing in to the services is an option. As commented, deleting system frameworks can yield a compromised system, a more crash-prone system and must be inspected / repeated each time a software update is released by Apple.

Answer (score 7):

Honestly I don't see any benefit in removing the Twitter/Facebook libraries. It may break the installed version as well as lead to problems when upgrading to 10.8.1 etc.

If you want to be sure that nothing you do is ever ending up in Twitter or Facebook just don't log in to these services in Preferences.

Comment: If it doesn't lead to problems with the next point release, I would suspect at the very least an OS update might just *replace* the stuff the OP removed...

Answer (score 2):

You can’t just remove it. It’s so tied into the OS that you can’t. If you remove some frameworks, it will cause some apps to crash. It’s better to just turn it off.

Comment: Well for experiment purposes I have removed the twitter stuff. Twitter has now gone from the sharing button, notifications & Mail, Contacts & Calendars (in System Prefs). No adverse effects so far. Surely Sharekit.framework is OSX and twitter, facebook , weibo etc are just plugins?

Comment: I didn’t quite understand “Sharekit.framework is OSX…”?

Comment: @Georgia: please document how you did remove your twitter stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove anything you want from the *ShareKit.framework* folder. Keep the files you remove in a backup folder and replace them if there is a problem. You Mac won't break, the service that requires the particular framework just won't work. I've removed everything from there and my machine still booted and worked, just in a more limited way.
Don't be afraid to experiment.
Ultimately, if you don't provide your social passwords to OS X, it can't operate on those accounts. I don't know if it can pull passwords from Safari's password storage service, so keep that in mind if you let Safari remember your FB/Twitter passwords.